# SQL PHP syntax issue with CSV upload

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I've recently finished a PHP project where the user uploads a CSV, and these are daily uploads. The CSV contained 2-10 records/lines that the PHP has been custom coded for. However, today I ran into an issue where it only inserted 6 of 7 records into the database.

After inspecting, the SQL syntax error occurred on a line where all other inputs are in inches (3", 6") but the user had a typo in this record and it looks like feet (3',6'). Because of my values in PHP being wrapped in single quotes, it ran into an error, didn't insert and moved to the next record(s), all of which had the right syntax for inches. Here is my str_replace line:

```
$col_list = '`'.str_replace(',','`,`',$table_cols[$tableno]).'`';
```

I think that's where the issue would be addressed, but not sure. Could someone help me out on this where, in the future, typos between quotations can be ignored and still be inserted?

Comment: you should have done mysqli_escape_string or prepared statements to prevent that. Mysqli prepared statements is the way to go: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: I just read through that, and I see that it's a general rule for the actual SQL statement, mine of which is:
$q .= "INSERT INTO ".$tablenames[$tableno]." (".$col_list.") VALUES (";

So would I just convert this into a prepared statement? Or would I have to create other parameters for it as well?

Comment: Let me reword. Use prepared statements with parameter variables, being ?: Example INSERT INTO ___ (Col1,Col2) VALUES(?,?);

Comment: Ok, I think I see. The issue is I have my columns and table columns in arrays so my INSERT statement above shows that I'm inserting the CSV elements from my table columns array as values and then further down I have an implode statement that closes the parentheses from the INSERT statement. Since I'm not explicitly inserting certain values it has to be structured a bit differently I believe.

Comment: So you do a foreach on each csv row, bind the position of the csv array to a variable aka column, then bind_param, execute for each row's value

Comment: Thank you. I think after looking into your answer mysql_escape_string will probably work better for my problem, since I just need a quick fix for this typo which should ideally not happen much.

Comment: if you are only expecting ft then perhaps the single quotes are something you should detect before processing the file and show an error and not process the file at all until the user corrects it?

Comment: I actually do have QA errors like that in the preview table for the user, so that it shows them any errors before submitting, but I want to make sure if they do submit it, it won't just omit one record